# What is this constant?

Tags: thermodynamics

Doing physics exercises, I've come across this one, where I don't completely understand the meaning. The exercise is as follows:
Hydrogen gas enclosed in a box $V=5l$ is cooled down by $\Delta T=55K$. Find the amount of heat that was emitted during that process. For a two-atom gas like hydrogen ($H_2$), $к=\frac{7}{5}$.
What is this constant $к$?

Comment: It is the [heat capacity ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) [...pdf](http://catalog.conveyorspneumatic.com/Asset/FLS%20Specific%20Heat%20Capacities%20of%20Gases.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The ratio $\gamma = \frac{c_p}{c_v}$ is the ratio of heat capacity of a gas under constant pressure (expanding with temperature) and under constant volume (not doing work against the environment). Obviously, the latter will be smaller. The ratio is a function of the number of degrees of freedom of the gas. For mono-atomic gases, it is $\frac{5}{3}$, for diatomic, $\frac75$ (two additional modes: rotation) until the temperature becomes so high that vibrations become important - then it becomes $\frac86$.

In your case, they used $\kappa$ instead of $\gamma$. Different conventions...

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) for more details.

Comment: Can you help me solve this problem? If the amount of heat that was emitted is given by formula: $Q=m c \Delta T$, where $c$ is specific heat, how can I know the mass of hydrogen in that box?

Comment: You cannot solve that without at least one additional piece of information. Perhaps the hydrogen was at STP when it was occupying the full 5 liters? In that case you know how many moles of hydrogen there are (22.4 liters = 1 mole = 2 gram of hydrogen).

Comment: What do you mean by STP?

Comment: STP = [standard temperature and pressure](https://www.thoughtco.com/stp-in-chemistry-607533).

Comment: In the formula $Q=mcΔT$, by $c$ do they mean $c_p$ or $c_v$?

Comment: That depends - is the volume or the pressure constant?

Comment: Volume, so, it should be $c_v$?